# Is it safe to eat venison tartare from an animal that was harvested in the wild?

Tags: food-safety, raw-meat, venison, tartare

I recently watched a cooking show on how to prepare [venison tartare](https://goodfood.uktv.co.uk/recipe/venison-tartare/).  There was an explanation given by the host stating that the venison was acquired at a local deer farm.  There was no mention regarding meat that was harvested in the wild.

[Deer farming](http://www.nelsonroadvet.com/articles/large-animal-exotics/deer-farming/) keeps the deer in a controlled environment where their diet is controlled as well as the deer receiving the proper vaccinations.

**Since wild deer don't have a controlled environment or vaccinations, would it still be safe to eat raw meat from deer harvested in the wild?**

Answer (score 10):

If you really want to eat that raw, freezing the meat at -4 deg F (-20°C) or lower for 30 days or more should kill most if not all the types of parasites found in deer.

Different parasites die at different temperatures, for example:

- [Anisakiasis](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/anisakiasis/faqs.html) (fish worms) can be treated at -4°F (-20°C) or below for 7 days (total time).
- [Trichinellosis](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/trichinellosis/prevent.html) (pork worms) treated by freezing pork less than 6 inches thick for 20 days at 5°F (-15°C) to kill any worms.
- [Venison](https://www.extension.umn.edu/food/food-safety/preserving/meat-fish/parasites-and-wild-game-venison/) -4°F (-20°C) or below for 4 days.

Comment: 30 days!  Oh, wow!

Comment: Do you have a reference for this claim? I'd have suspected a lower temp would have been needed.

Comment: Ok, I guess I was off by 4 degrees. I revised my answer to be more accurate and linked to the articles